# Error while unlocking windows phone 7.1 device(Lumia 800). Windows Phone Developer Registration

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

1)unable to connect to phone. please check that the zune software is running and that

Zune's sync partnership with your phone has been established.

2)Error communicating with the Windows Phone Dev Center. 
Please set the correct date and time on the phone, 
check the Internet connection on device and try again later (ErrorCode: 0x64)

3)Please set the correct date and time on the phone, check the Internet connection and try again later.

Steps we followed,
reboot the phone,

1)reset its factory settings again,

2)try to register with turned off WiFi, tried with mobile data.

3)run with/without sim-card

4)turned off skype

Any ideas?

Thanks & Regards,
Pallam Madhukar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since December 31th 2014, it's not possible to unlock a Windows Phone 7 device through normal ways.

http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-ends-unlocking-windows-phone-7x-devices-developers-dec-31